# jQuery BlockUI Plugin method blockUI how to display just image without any background

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here is on the sample page http://jquery.malsup.com/block/ is an example of an overlay message with an image:

`$.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });`

But I want to display just an image, so I took out the h1 tag:

`$.blockUI({ message: '<img src="busy.gif" />' });`

But there is still a background color under my image. How can I remove it?

According with source code of jQuery BlockUI Plugin (v2) it is wrapping the message in an h2 tag

```
if (title) $m.append('<h1>'+title+'</h1>');
if (message) $m.append('<h2>'+message+'</h2>');
```

so it looks like there is no way without modification of the source code to pass just an image tag.

I might modify the library source code to introduce a new param like `image` with a condition:

```
if (image) $m.append(image);
```

and than I could declare my image like this:

```
$.blockUI({ image: '<img src="busy.gif" />' });
```

Any more ideas?

Comment: Makes no sense.  If the first example works, then there's no reason why the second wouldn't work.  You should probably post a live example.

Comment: @Sparky672 it is working in both ways. Just there h2 tag was added every time. See question updates

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding your question and requirements.  Perhaps you can post a live example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default you got that:

```
    // styles for the message when blocking; if you wish to disable
    // these and use an external stylesheet then do this in your code:
    // $.blockUI.defaults.css = {};
    css: {
        padding:    0,
        margin:     0,
        width:      '30%',
        top:        '40%',
        left:       '35%',
        textAlign:  'center',
        color:      '#000',
        border:     '3px solid #aaa',
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        cursor:     'wait'
    },
```

So if you don't want any of these just do that in your code:

```
$.blockUI.defaults.css = {};
```

Or if you want to exclude background and border just go with that insteard:

```
$.blockUI.defaults.css = { 
            padding: 0,
            margin: 0,
            width: '30%',
            top: '40%',
            left: '35%',
            textAlign: 'center',
            cursor: 'wait'
        };
```

Basically using that external stylesheet you may specify any css style you want.

Answer (score 9):

This one works perfectly

```
$.blockUI({ message: '<img src="your.gif" />' ,
css: { width: '4%', border:'0px solid #FFFFFF',cursor:'wait',backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF'},
  overlayCSS:  { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',opacity:0.0,cursor:'wait'} 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also override some css params when calling blockUI(). Like this:

```
  $.blockUI({
    'message':$('#div-'+$(this).attr('id')),
    'css':{width:539,height:539,top:'80px',left:($(window).width()-539)/2+'px',border:0}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the css for overlay

```
$.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.opacity = 0;
```

More here: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#options

Comment: $.blockUI({ overlayCSS.opacity = 5.0 });...is is currect...??Help...??

Comment: @Kalyan 

    $.blockUI({
    overlayCSS: {
            backgroundColor: '#C8E6FF',
            opacity: 0,
            cursor: 'wait'
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

[just hit this url : https://sites.google.com/site/atgcorner/Downhome/javascript/jqueryblockuipopupwithimage-1](https://sites.google.com/site/atgcorner/Downhome/javascript/jqueryblockuipopupwithimage-1)

then with a litle implementation in my code..

```
 

var spinnerImg = new Image();


spinnerImg.src = "${spinnerImage}";

    function loadpage() { 
        $.ajax({ url: 'wait.jsp', cache: false }); 
    } 

    function testload(){
         var msg = "";
         $.blockUI({ 
            message: $(' Wait a moment..'),             
             css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#fff', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5,            
            color: '#000' 
        } }); 
         loadpage();    
         setTimeout($.unblockUI, 6000);

    }
```

IT Works fine (i'm currently using FF 31.0 & Chrome 36.0)