# Opacity attribute only appears in Docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, opacity, blockui

I have a Laravel app that is using the Metronic theme. As a part of the theme, they have their own implementation of BlockUI. I've been using this for years with no trouble. When the app runs bare-metal, everything works as expected.

However, when I Dockerize the app, everything works fine, but I notice that an extra `opacity` attribute is being applied to the BlockUI element(s). Not only that, but it's doing it on all of the pages *except one*.

Here is how it should appear (bare-metal version):

[image: BlockUI working properly]

As you can see, it darkens the DataTable and puts up a "Please wait..." box when an AJAX request is made.

Now here's the exact same page, but within a Docker container:

[image: BlockUI with mysterious 'opacity' attribute added]

In this case, the "Please wait..." box is only barely visible because it's been given an opacity of about 0.1 and you cannot even tell that the DataTable has been darkened any at all.

How can I track down where this is coming from? It only happens when the exact same app (no changes) is run from within a Docker container and on all pages but one. (The "Orders by Print Type" page works fine. No clue why.)

Here's the Dockerfile, in case it might have something to do with this:

```dockerfile
FROM php:apache

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Set our application folder as an environment variable
ENV APP_HOME /var/www/html

# Set working directory
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# Use the default production configuration
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

# Copy over project-specific PHP settings
COPY ./docker-config/php/local.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

# Get NodeJS
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -

# Install all the system dependencies and enable PHP modules 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      libicu-dev \
      libpq-dev \
      libmcrypt-dev \
      libpng-dev \
      libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
      libfreetype6-dev \
      git \
      libzip-dev \
      zip \
      unzip \
      nodejs \
      build-essential \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql \
      --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
      --enable-gd \
      --with-freetype=/usr/include/ \
      --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
      intl \
      pcntl \
      pdo_mysql \
      pdo_pgsql \
      pgsql \
      zip \
      opcache \
      gd \
    && pecl install -o -f redis \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer


# Change uid and gid of apache to docker user uid/gid
RUN usermod -u $uid $user && groupmod -g $uid $user

# Copy existing application directory + permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . $APP_HOME

# Change the web_root to laravel /var/www/html/public folder
RUN sed -i -e "s/html/html\/public/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# Fix the .env file for production.
RUN mv "$APP_HOME/.env.production" "$APP_HOME/.env"

# Enable apache module rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Compile CSS & JS
RUN npm run production

# Install all PHP dependencies
RUN composer install --no-interaction

# Create mountpoints and link them.
RUN ln -s /mnt/orders /var/www/html/public/orders

# Run artisan commands to set things up properly
RUN php artisan key:generate
RUN php artisan storage:link

# Optimization for production
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
RUN php artisan config:cache
RUN php artisan route:cache
RUN php artisan view:cache

# Set the maintainer info metadata
LABEL maintainer="Sturm <email_hidden>"
```

And here is the relevant portion of the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
  # Laravel app (Apache & PHP services with Laravel)
  schedule:
    build:
      args:
        user: www-data
        uid: 1000
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: "sturmb/sky-schedule:2021.6.1"
    container_name: schedule
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - /mnt/jobs_main:/mnt/jobs_main
      - /mnt/orders:/mnt/orders
    depends_on:
      - schedule-db
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
      - "4543:443"
    networks:
      - web
```

Comment: Post your dockerfile to the question

Comment: @TarunLalwani Dockerfile posted.

Comment: I hope you have tested both versions in incognito to rule out any kind of weird caching?

Comment: I wouldn't be much of a web developer if I didn't. Caching isn't the issue.

Comment: Lol. Sorry sometime you gotta ask what you gotta ask. This is the weirdest one i have seen, i can't correlate yet what could be wrong

Comment: How do you run the container? Please add either the command or the `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Clarifying your term usage of "bare-metal", dockerzied application is also running on bare-metal, on the same kernel. Difference only being that this kernel is read-only. There must be either some change on your files(some version difference?) or it somehow detects dynamically different context and adjusts settings.

Comment: In this context, when I use the term 'bare-metal,' I am referring to a non-dockerized version. i.e., running on my dev system with an AMP stack installed (specifically, Laragon for Apache & PHP). When dockerized, as you can see from the Dockerfile I posted, I'm building it from the official `php:apache` image. Regardless, it runs on my dev PC as well. I do not see where there are different kernels, could you please clarify?

Comment: On your laragon environment, does this issue appear if you do an npm run production instead of using dev assets?

Comment: That's a good thought, @Msencenb, but I just gave that a try and I'm still getting the correct opacity. On a side note, while attempting to test whether or not those three artisan commands made a difference on the bare-metal dev PC, I discovered that running `php artisan config:cache` seems to screw up the app, so I have to `config:clear` it. (Yet it seems to not be a problem in the Dockerfile.)

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean difference on on kernels, instead possible difference on your dependency/package versions which might cause this. Are you 100% that software is identical in container and on your dev system?

Comment: As far as packages/libraries, both versions are using the exact same `package-lock.json` and `composer.lock` files. Checking `phpinfo()`, however, there are differences. e.g., dev is using a Windows-based PHP (from Laragon) v7.4.16. Container is using a Linux-based PHP v7.4.12. When the container is on my local machine, it's running from WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04. On our live server, it's Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: Could it be the difference between v7.4.16 and v7.4.12? Can you not build a container that is identical to your dev machine? Or, upgrade your dev machine? As it stands, you're saying something like, "my application behaves differently when I run it on different versions of the platform," to which we can only answer, "meh". If it's on the same versions, then we have something to discuss... Also, can you run `env` in your container and on your dev-machine and confirm the diffs.

Comment: @Sturm do you know where that opacity value is coming from? E.g. which css?

Comment: First I would try double check if behaves the same in other browsers, to make sure this is not the side effect of some extensions from your current browser.  I think your dockerized version for whatever reason possibly override the default opacity, maybe search for part of this string in your docker container?
`$.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.opacity`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636157/jquery-blockui-plugin-method-blockui-how-to-display-just-image-without-any-backg

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I get what you mean about the two different versions of PHP, but A) If you see my Dockerfile, you'll notice that I'm pulling the latest version of PHP for the container. i.e., 7.4.12 _is_ the latest version, even if 7.4.16 is out. I can't do anything except possibly downgrade my dev version of PHP just because the Docker images are lagging behind. And B) A minor point release between versions causing this problem? I could understand if it was a major point release (7.5) or a major version update (8.0), but not this. Possible? Sure. Likely? I doubt it.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer There is such a vast difference between the two environments that it's almost useless trying to compare the two. In addition, there are so many environment variables that I don't have a clue what they're doing that I couldn't possibly speculate if any of them are causing this issue. And, again, I find it unlikely that an environment variable would be the cause. But, hey, I could be wrong. Have a look: https://www.diffchecker.com/JVPD6Bdu

Comment: @naimdjon In my second screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCadC.png), you can see that the opacity attribute is being applied to the element's style tag, which suggests that it's being done programmatically rather than predefined in a CSS file somewhere. The only thing is that it's not coming from any code I've written.

Comment: @runwuf I checked Firefox and Edge and got the same result. I'm not sure how to check everything in the docker container for that string.

Comment: @Sturm if you have this app root checkout on your local/bare metal somewhere, if you search `blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.opacity` do you see anywhere in the code that is setting this?

Comment: The easiest solution: Assume docker is right, and your personal machine is wrong. Then, fix the problem in docker. If it works in docker, it works in prod. Lit. nobody cares if it doesn't work on your machine. (I mean that nicely ;).

Answer (score 0):

There are many moving parts here, therefore it is not trivial to pinpoint exactly where the change in your element is being applied from. One possible way to find this out could be to use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and watch for changes being made to the DOM tree. Something along the line of:

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log("Detected change: ", mutation);
    });    
});

var blockElement = document.getElementsByClassName("blockUI blockMsg blockElement");
mutationObserver.observe(blockElement, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ["style"] });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @naimdjon. I've got the observer working, but all it can tell me is that the `opacity` style is a part of the node when it is added to the DOM--but only in the Docker container. It's not a part of the node when running outside of a container.